# Append x amount of records in Access 2010

Tags: insert, count, append, ms-access-2010

I will explain my situation which will hopefully explain what I am trying to do.  I have a table that has our staff phone numbers, but I need to be able to see what the next 5 available numbers are.

I have tbl_ext, which is current numbers and tbl_temp, which is used to enter in a "starting" number, dependent on status (managers get 1xxx, sales get 2xxx, etc) .  I need to know if it would be possible to "count" the next 5 numbers that are not in tbl_ext and insert these into tbl_temp.

Hopefully this makes some sense, as I am starting to wonder if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will create the next five numbers for extensions that start with '1xxx'. You didn't mention the format of the field (text or number), or if you store Area Code + Exchange + Ext.
You also didn't mntion how many different 'status' there are (1, 2, 3, ...). You can either clone the code and repeat for 1-9 or, you could select the unique high-order digit of all extensions. I can update the answer when you procide more detail.

```
Public Function Create_Phone_Numbers()
Dim db  As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i   As Integer
Dim iLoop   As Integer
Dim iExt    As Integer
Dim iStatus As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb

For iStatus = 1 To 9
    If iStatus = 999 Then   ' Change this line to skip unused numbers
        ' Do nothing - skip this
    Else                ' It's a number we want.
        strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 tbl_Ext.PhoneExt FROM tbl_Ext GROUP BY tbl_Ext.PhoneExt HAVING (((tbl_Ext.PhoneExt) Like '" & iStatus & "*')) ORDER BY tbl_Ext.PhoneExt DESC;"
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
        If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
            iExt = rst!PhoneExt
            For i = 1 To 5
                strSQL = "insert into tbl_Temp (PhoneExt) Select " & iExt + i & " As Expr1;"
                db.Execute strSQL
            Next i
        End If
    End If
Next iStatus
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  It is what I needed.  As for the questions you asked, the fields are set as numbers and it is only the 5 digits extensions that I am after, no need to worry about the other information.  As the ranges, there are 7 different "Status" levels, so this will be setup for those 7 different levels.

Comment: Since I don't know if the 7 levels are all together (1-7) or maybe 1-5, 8 ,9, I will update the code so that it will handle up to 9 groupings. I will place an "IF" to skip a non-existant number, so you can modify that IF to suit your needs.